# Normalizing to first form inside Microsoft Access - are there semi-automatic methods?

Tags: sql, ms-access, normalization

Imagine you have tens of thousands of records like the sample below and you have a column which has hundreds of "Favorite Foods" in each row that need to be normalized to their own table and rows. Doing this manually would take forever, and the ";" symbol, as shown in Steak; Grapes; Eggs, gets in the way of Microsoft Access's table wizard and it doesn't seem to work.

How can I semi-automatically get these pesky rows with multiple items divided by ;'s to be normalized in their own table?

```
 Incorrect
 ╔══════╤═══════════╤═══════════════════╗
 ║  ID  │ Name      │  Favorite Foods   ║ 
 ╠══════╪═══════════╪═══════════════════╣
 ║  1   │ John      │Steak; Grapes; Eggs║ 
 ╟──────┼───────────┼───────────────────╢
 ║  2   │ Jeff      │    Eggs; Toast    ║ 
 ╟──────┼───────────┼───────────────────╢
 ║  3   │ Joel      │Pear; Onion; Apples║ 
 ╚══════╧═══════════╧═══════════════════╝


 Normalized
 ╔══════╤═══════════╗ ╔══════╤═══════════════════╗
 ║  ID  │ Name      ║ ║  ID  │  Favorite Foods   ║
 ╠══════╪═══════════╣ ╠══════╪═══════════════════╣
 ║  1   │ John      ║ ║  1   │       Steak       ║
 ╟──────┼───────────╢ ╟──────┼───────────────────╢
 ║  2   │ Jeff      ║ ║  1   │       Grapes      ║
 ╟──────┼───────────╢ ╟──────┼───────────────────╢
 ║  3   │ Joel      ║ ║  1   │       Eggs        ║
 ╚══════╧═══════════╝ ╟──────┼───────────────────╢
                      ║  2   │       Eggs        ║
                      ╟──────┼───────────────────╢
                      ║  2   │       Toast       ║
                      ╟──────┼───────────────────╢
                      ║  3   │       Pear        ║
                      ╟──────┼───────────────────╢
                      ║  3   │       Onion       ║
                      ╟──────┼───────────────────╢
                      ║  3   │       Apples      ║
                      ╚══════╧═══════════════════╝
```

Comment: Note that your nomralized solution is not really normalized. A food item could be requested by 0,1,or more customers, as a result, you have a M-M relationship. Add to this the fact that the same customer may visit and make a different order. Say, Jeff can come one day and ask for Steak and Pear.

Comment: If the table contains rows in the low million range, you can use Excel Text to Columns to create a broader table and them mechanically fold this back into the original data, dropping duplicates. Un-pivoting is a  classically hard problem and one that does not have good general solutions.

Comment: +1 for readable ASCII Graphics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the users' `ID` and `Name` into a new table.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT o.ID, o.Name
INTO tblUsers
FROM OldTable AS o;
```

Create a new empty table, `tblFavorites`, to hold the users' `[Favorite Foods]`.  Then create and run a VBA procedure which uses DAO recordsets to extract the information from `OldTable` and add it to `tblFavorites`.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rsSrc As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsDest As DAO.Recordset
Dim varFoods As Variant
Dim varItem As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rsSrc = db.OpenRecordset("OldTable", dbOpenTable)
Set rsDest = db.OpenRecordset("tblFavorites", dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly)

Do While Not rsSrc.EOF
    varFoods = Split(rsSrc![Favorite Foods], ";")
    For Each varItem In varFoods
        rsDest.AddNew
        rsDest!ID = rsSrc!ID
        rsDest![Favorite Foods] = Trim(varItem)
        rsDest.Update
    Next
    rsSrc.MoveNext
Loop
```